# Android Volley API (Google IO 2013) Log does not show anything for socket timeout scenario?

Tags: android, android-volley

This might be a bug with Volley itself.  I have verbose logging set to true. I run one Volley request that goes over http successfully and it logs everything ok. Then I add another request to the queue that times out and volley does not log anything. I do catch a volley timeout error but nothing is written to the log. nothing about the http request at all. How is it possible for volley to skip logging and yet return a Volley timout exception?

EDIT:  This might be that I did not have the volley logs on for the device in question. I will test this again and update later.